# Full multivariate Polynomial Code based on an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I want to write Matlab code for full multivariate polynomial based on my algorithm as follows:

Suppose we have:

```
A=[1 2 3 4;
   5 6 7 8]
```

the input dimension here is L=4 and the number of rows is M=2.
to make a full multivariate polynomial I want to use convolution or bsxfunc built in functions. But it is a little different according to my customized algorithm:

(Let write dimension in this way when the order of polynomial equals to 2):

```
[X1.X1  X1.X2  X1.X3  X1.X4 ; X2.X2  X2.X3  X2.X4 ; X3.X3  X3.X4 ;  X4.X4]
```

all terms for `order=2` is like above. For `order=3` , we have:

```
X1.*(the first column of above)
X2.*(the second column of above)
X3.*(the third column of above)
X4.*(the forth column of above)
```

plus previous results of order=2.

When R=1: M1 is the number of terms for full multivariate polynomial mode.

```
R=2  :    (adding previous terms to following terms)
X1 . M1=[X1.X1;X1.X2;X1.X3;X1.X4]  ,  X2 . M2=[X2.x2; X2.X3; X2.X4]  .......
```

I can not generate this by using built in `bsxfun`. It needs to avoid repetitive terms, because when `x1` multiplies by `x2`, I want to avoid multiplying `x2` by `x1`.

Final result should be like this:

```
Res=[1    5;
     2    6; 
     3    7; 
     4    8; 
     1   25; 
     2   30; 
     3   35; 
     4   40; 
     4   36; 
     6   42; 
      ...  ;
   4^4 8^4];
```

How can I write code for different dimensions and different orders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I got everything right. But I think that's what you're looking for.
It maybe can be further vectorized.

```
A = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ; 
      5, 6, 7, 8 ];

L = length(A);
X = A(1,:);
Y = A(2,:);
for ii = 1:1:L-1
    X = [ X , A(1,:).^(ii+1)];
    Y = [ Y , A(2,:).^(ii+1)];
    if ii < L/2
    X = [ X , A(1,:).*circshift(A(1,:)',ii)'];
    Y = [ Y , A(2,:).*circshift(A(2,:)',ii)'];  
    end
end
```

result = [ X' , Y' ]

leads to:

```
 results =
   1           5
   2           6
   3           7
   4           8
   1          25
   4          36
   9          49
  16          64
   4          40
   2          30
   6          42
  12          56
   1         125
   8         216
  27         343
  64         512
   1         625
  16        1296
  81        2401
 256        4096
```

Basically it's the same you could reach with `bsxfun`, except the additional if-condition.
That works for different orders. For different dimensions, I would put everything into a function and cascade it.

Comment: thank for your answer. However, the answer is wrong
because you did not consider triple terms (and also developing for higher orders) like: (x1)*(x2)*(x3).